# Can you specify a date in the future for the Bitcoin transaction

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, raw-transaction

I just came across this Transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/cf77c2b888916c0debfb801d3d129ba5b7f6445e0dd6db9238b313b51369024c

```
Received Time:  2063-08-04 05:00:33
```

Raw Transaction: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/cf77c2b888916c0debfb801d3d129ba5b7f6445e0dd6db9238b313b51369024c

Is it just one case, maybe some kind of bug, which has already been solved, or is this a normal behavior?

Is there any official information regarding this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a glitch with blockchain.info, there is no "time" encoded in a bitcoin transaction itself so that number is likely just when blockchain.info received the transaction.

In general though, it is possible to create a transaction which is only valid after a certain point in time or a certain block height in the blockchain, by using the "locktime" component of a transaction. If a locktime on the transaction is set, the transaction can only be included in a block after that point, not before, which may be of interest to you.

Comment: If you check the very last lines of the raw transaction, you can find the 'time' field with the value of 2953429233. And the 'lock_time' is set to 0. Here is another transaction like the one from my original post: https://blockchain.info/rawtx/da71fda48795fbdf05ca522ceaa7ac34bef68ca6973f33ff5ec764bdfcff045c And again, "lock_time": 0, "time": 1574921809

Comment: @GSazheniuk yes, but then"time" field is something blockchain.info has made, it is not part of the raw transaction, that's what I said in my answer

Comment: Blockchain.info is a private website, it's not the block chain, most of the information they show is fairly nonsensical. They've a history of displaying misleading, incorrect, or just plain ridiculous things about transactions.

Comment: @MeshCollider Just our of curiosity - did you check raw transaction in any other source(s) when you said that 'there is no "time" encoded in a bitcoin transaction itself '?

Comment: @GSazheniuk I'm very familiar with the raw transaction format :) you can see the two transaction serialisation formats here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#transaction-id